# sed replace inside shell file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, replace

I have  a shell file which needs to perform a replace of some text in a php file.

The line that needs replacing is:

```
$database = $db."_db";
```

The actual sed command needs to contain a variable so not sure what i should be escaping and where?

```
#!/bin/sh

sed -i s/$db."db"/$DATABASE/ mysql_connect.php
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enclose the string in single quotes to prevent variable expansion.

```
sed -i s/'$db."_db"'/$DATABASE/ mysql_connect.php
```

to replace all occurrences of `$db."_db"` with the value of `$DATABASE`.